# Alter index name using liquibase

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to alter the index name using liquibase using the below code, but it is not working. The same sql statement is working directly in the db.

```
<changeSet author="sai" dbms="postgresql">
  <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
   <indexExists indexName="employee_id_idx" schemaName="public"/>
  </preConditions>
  <sql>alter INDEX employee_id_idx RENAME TO department_id_idx</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Could anyone please let me know if there is any other way of doing alter to the index name using liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with the same code. But when we run the code if we have any error in the code, then it will be saved in `DBChangeLog` table, we need to remove that particular record and run again. This resolved the issue